# What's this mysterious symbol used for the insert page break shortcut in Apple's Pages?

Tags: iwork-pages

I'm familiar with the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key symbol, but the second symbol one leaves me stumped.

> [image: Cmd +Something]

I tried <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> -- no luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the article [Apple Mac OS X Keyboard Symbols](https://web.archive.org/web/20200714183106/https://www.osxkeyboardshortcuts.com/keyboard-symbols.html), the symbol refers to the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

And [according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/keyboard-shortcuts-tanc0ffef022/mac), the shortcut keys to insert a Page Break is indeed:

> Command + ENTER

or

> Command + Return + Fn

As explained by Denis de Bernardy, Apple differentiates between the Enter key and the Return key, even if they are on the same physical location.

Comment: It's the latter for me

Comment: `-`Just to provide context. On keyboards with a standard layout of 100+ keys (101 US std, 102 EU std, 106 Japanese std.. etc) the enter key is in the bottom right as part of the numeric key.
`-`Functionally the enter key's primary use is similar to that of the = in an equation. It is used to denote the end of a command. Originally enter was located next to the space bar. 
`-`The return key is based on typewriter design & primary use is to denote a new line. During early evolution of computing it was realised that when typing commands/code it would be more natural to also use the return key

Answer (score 3):

Press 'command' and the 'fn' keys, then hit return. (I have no idea what the key is in the drop down menu, either!)

Answer (score 2):

This symbol is "Enter" in Number Pad. If you are using a MacBook without Number Pad, press Fn + Cmd + Return to get this shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

(Command + (fn + return))

I'm pretty sure the (fn + return) part is meant to be a "new page" function, seeing as (fn + up arrow) or (fn + down arrow) are for page up and page down functions, respectively. This answer is a bit late but just in case anyone stumbles across this in the future, I hope I was able to help. :)